# Data from column to row

Tags: stata

I would like to accomplish the following:

1  date1

1  date2

1  date3

into a single row:

1 date1 date2 date3

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is currently very unclear. (1) Please take the time to [format your question properly](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). (2) Include some code that shows [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) in the form of a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
clear
input id date
1 1
1 2
1 3
end
gen t=_n
reshape wide date, i(id) j(t)
```